# multivaluedictkeyerror : key not found in <<QueryDict: {}>

Tags: django-forms

my template contains a form :

```
<form action="." method="post">
<label {#for="q"#}>Search: </label>
<br>    
<input type="text" name="username" value="USERNAME" />
<br>
<input type="text" name="password" value="PASSWORD"/>
<br>    
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

But in my Django code when I write:

```
def register(request):
    userID = request.POST['username']
```

I am getting the error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /register/
"Key 'username' not found in < QueryDict: {}>"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not POSTing to the URL. You should not try to use `request.POST` in a GET request; make sure to check the request method first.